# sort the elements in java using priority queue

Tags: java, queue, comparator, priority-queue, comparable

I want to sort the elements using Priority Queue in Java.

Here is my code. What is wrong in it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class PQ {
    static class IntCompare implements Comparator<Integer>{
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
            if(arg0 > arg1)
                return -1;
            else if(arg0 < arg1)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
   }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 1, 3, 8, 5, 2, 6 };

        Comparator<Integer> c = new IntCompare();
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq=new PriorityQueue<>(c);

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            pq.add(a[i]);

        System.out.println(pq);
    }
}
```

my output is:

```
8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3
```

correct output:

```
8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Your PriorityQueue is ordered, the `toString` just outputs them in no particular order (as clearly stated in the Javadoc). Also consider using `Comparator.reverseOrder()` over reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `System.out.println(pq)`, the `toString` method is called implicitly.

The [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) method of `PriorityQueue`  extends from `AbstractCollection`, which

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
>   order they are returned by **its iterator**, enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]").

While the [`iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) of `PriorityQueue` is not guaranteed to traverse in particular order:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

since the queue is based on [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

You can poll elements one by one to get ordered elements:

```
while (pq.size() != 0) {
    System.out.print(pq.poll() + ","); // 8,6,5,3,2,1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `poll()` all the elements until the queue is empty and save them somewhere to get them ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, list contains items in sorted order. **The priority key by itself not maintain the elements in sorted order, it just keeps the top element as minimum or maximum based on your implementation of the PQ.**

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        int a[]={1,3,8,5,2,6};
        Comparator<Integer> c = new IntCompare();
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq=new PriorityQueue<>(c);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            pq.add(a[i]);
        ArrayList<Integer> list  = new ArrayList<>();
        while(!pq.isEmpty()){
            list.add(pq.poll());
        }
        for(Integer i : list)
            System.out.println(i);
}
```